# AWS cognito && nodejs - How do I add my client secret to validate my tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to set up a node REST wrapper for cognito to act as auth for my web service.

Tokens are generated from node and sent to the client via endpoints like `/login`

How do I add my client secret to the SDK?